# Implementing Steam OpenID for iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, openid, steam

I'm trying to implement Steam Authentication via OpenID for iOS using [this framework](http://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/). I already translated the demo to Swift 3 and made it work with Google. Now I'm trying to get it to work with Steam and I don't know where to find some of its configuration. To make the app work with Google I use this information:

```
let kClientID = "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
let KRedirectURI = URL(string: "com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx:/oauthredirect")
let kIssuer = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com")
```

I've being looking in their dev wiki but so far I could just find how to get the API key. Would you have this information? It is my first contact with OpenID and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm kind of facing the same issue? any updates? :)

Comment: @AhmadF no, I didn't get it to work